# Fixed content layout in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Just a quick question. I am using TinyMCE with "template" and "noneditable" plugins. I am trying to use a template to provide a layout for users. I applied "mceNonEditable" and "mceEditable" on necessary html elements but when the template is loaded in the editor, the user can remove tags and not just edit the content in those. How should I go about it? How do I create a fixed template where html tags cannot be deleted?

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what we are looking for is not supported: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:noneditable.

see: "Nested editable elements are not currently supported. You would not be able to edit the cell contents in the following table:"

```
<table class="mceNonEditable">
 <tr>
  <td class="mceEditable">
   Contents
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

If anyone has a workaround, please do provide.